# OpenCV: Finding the upper and lower bounds for a color HSV

Tags: android, opencv

The following code reads the pixel in the center and returned three values which i assumed was `H = data[0], S data[1], V = data[2]`, how do I get the upper and lower bounds HSV value?

**Note:** The color pixel I'm reading is Green.

> E/data: H:90.0  S:113.0  V:144.0

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);

            int width= bitmap.getWidth();
            int height=bitmap.getHeight();

            int centerX=width/2;
            int centerY=height/2;
            srcMat = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, srcMat);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, srcMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
            srcMat.convertTo(srcMat, CvType.CV_64FC3); //http://answers.opencv.org/question/14961/using-get-and-put-to-access-pixel-values-in-java/
            double[] data = srcMat.get(centerX, centerY);
            Log.e("data", String.valueOf("H:"+data[0]+" S:"+data[1]+" V:"+data[2]));
            Log.e("dlength", String.valueOf(data.length));
            Mat matHSV = new Mat(0,0,CvType.CV_64FC3);
```

Also by adding the following three lines of code, i'll receive an error saying bitmap == null, so im not really sure if the pixel reading worked or not.

```
matHSV.put(0,0,data);
Utils.matToBitmap(matHSV, bb);
imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bb);
```

Image I'm Reading:
[image]

Comment: Finding color's upper and lower bounds is not the same as finding the average color.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542584/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert `Mat` to HSV model with `Imgproc.cvtColor()` method:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

Than find `min/max` Hue value over each pixel (with  `Mat.get(int,int)` method) - and thats `min` and `max` is will be the answer: lower and upper bounds for a color in HSV model.

NB! [Hue for OpenCV 8-bit images is Hue/2](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) because Hue value in "normal" model is between 0 and 360, and grater than 255 - max value for byte. So if You need color bounds for "normal" HSV model (not HSV for Android OpenCV), You shuld multiply it by 2.